# Two-dimensional arrays - finding the total of 1 row

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I'm sitting here, trying to figure out how to work with two-dimensional arrays.

I've obviously got 1 array named "row" and another named "column" so it's creating a matrix.(They're not actually names row and column, but it's easier to call them that)

My problem is, however, that I have to gather all values in a row, and return the total, that is calculated through this.

My code so far looks like this:

```
public void udskrivFravaer(int[][] fravaer) {

    for (int i1 = 0; i1 < fravaer.length; i1++) {
        for (int i2 = 0; i2 < fravaer[i1].length; i2++) {
            System.out.print(fravaer[i1][i2] + ",");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}   

public int samletFravaer(int[][] fravaer, int elevNr) {
    int samletFravaer = 0;
    for (int i1 = 0; i1 < fravaer[elevNr].length; i1++) {
        samletFravaer += fravaer[elevNr][i1];
    }
    System.out.println(samletFravaer);
    return samletFravaer;
}
```

I haven't inserted a return statement yet, so don't bother commenting on that please.
I really can't find the issue in my code, but obviously something's not working as intended.

EDIT: Editing for Zyn

Comment: samletFravaer = samletFravaer + fravaer[i1][i2]; replace zero with i1

Comment: Yes, and I suppose that is what I want it to do, but when I do such, Eclipse tells me my first for-loop becomes a dead code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're attempting to add all the values of one row then this appears to be the issue:

```
samletFravaer = samletFravaer + fravaer[0][i2];
```

You need to change this to:

```
samletFravaer = samletFravaer + fravaer[i1][i2];
```

Edit - this will print out the total:

```
public int samletFravaer(int[][] fravaer, int elevNr) {
    int samletFravaer = 0;
    for(int i1 = 0 ; i1 < fravaer[elevNr].length ; i1++)
    {
        samletFravaer += fravaer[elevNr][i1];
    }

    System.out.println( samletFravaer );
    return samletFravaer;
}
```

Second edit - you are not calling your method. Change your call to:

```
public void udskrivFravaer(int[][] fravaer) {

    for (int i1 = 0; i1 < fravaer.length; i1++) {
        samletFravaer( fravaer, i1 );
    }
}
```

Comment: If I do this, Eclipse tells me
 for(int i1 = 0 ; i1 < fravaer.length ; i1++)

becomes a dead code.

Comment: @JensJakob92 For me, Eclipse doesn't say that. Maybe you inserted a `return` statement somewhere?

Comment: @blueygh2 

Yeah, I realized I misplaced the return statement.
It doesn't complain now. Now I'm just trying to figure out how to print it out.

Comment: @JensJakob92 Somewhere else in the code (not in the method shown) `System.out.println(samletFravaer(arguments));`

Comment: After the inner loop `for(int i2 = 0 ; i2 < fravaer[i1].length ; i2++)` put `System.out.println( samletFravaer );` and after that line (for rows) otherwise put it after the outer loop. Warning: If this is returning the total from the entire 2D array then it's fine. If you're wanting to print the row total after each line don't forget to add `samletFravaer = 0`; after the print.

Comment: Updated my answer to print out the total as you require.

Comment: I may be missing something here, but isn't he asking for a sum of a specific row? The code above sums the entire array, if I'm right.

Comment: Yes, Arrem. I'm asking for a sum of a specific row - I thought that's what this would give.

Comment: Yeah that looks more right, cause it uses all parameters etc.
But for some reason it still won't print it out in my console.
It only prints out another method I've written above.

Comment: Can you add that code in - the print and the method call.

Comment: Could you try running my answer and see if that's what you need?

Comment: It's edited now.
Yes Arrem I would do that, but thing is I've got 2 classes (the one I'm working in, and another that is a static main), so your code kinda confuses me.. (no offense)

Comment: Updated my answer. You weren't actually calling your method.

Comment: Hmm, thanks.
Now the output in the console looks really messy though.
And I think the way it should come out, should be in alphabetic orders.
i.e. (a) first, then (b) afterwards.

Comment: Or maybe it isn't necessary, I don't know.

Comment: This will print out the total value of each row in order. So first value is the first row total. Second value is the second row total and so forth.

Comment: Yeah. This is what it prints out:

8
2,0,0,0,3,1,0,2,0,0,0,0,
0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
8
2,0,0,0,3,1,0,2,0,0,0,0,
15
1,2,1,2,1,2,0,2,0,0,4,0,
15
5,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,0,0,0,0,

Comment: Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: You could be running a version with two for loops. It was updated twice. Try copying it again? EDIT: Actually since it's repeating I'm sure you're using an older version. Copy his new `udskrivFravaer` method and try again. It should give you cleaner output.

Comment: Well, I think so.. I'm not even sure what I wanted for the output >_>
But yeah I suppose that's what I wanted.
Cause I needed the sum of each row, so yeah..

Answer (score 0):

You always calculate the first `row` values. because you're passing `fravaer[0][i2];` 0 for row, change it to the current row index that generated by the first loop, like:

```
samletFravaer = samletFravaer + fravaer[i1][i2];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static int sumArray(int[][] array, int row) {
        int sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < array[row].length; i++) {
            sum += array[row][i];
        }

        //Keep this line if you want to print it out every time the method is called.
        System.out.println(sum);
        return sum;
    }
```

That code takes a 2D array and a row index and returns the sum of the row. I'm really sorry for not modifying your original code, but the fact that it's in a different language made it harder for me to understand.